# Laptops, multiple screens, multiple interfaces

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Very new to using Linux on a laptop, and not sure what the best choices / pitfalls are.

I currently use a laptop with one mini DisplayPort, and one HDMI port. I use the laptop's built in screen, and then have a monitor connected to each of the ports. The HDMI screen flickers, blacks out a few times a minute, and a few times a day, turns into static and has to be power cycled. Occasionally, I even lose a window - I can Alt-Tab to it, but it never comes to the front and has to be killed.

Given the interfaces available, what would be the recommended method to drive 2 external monitors? Do I buy a DisplayPort splitter? An HDMI splitter? Daisy chain the monitors? Known issue and just upgrade the kernel?

This is Ubuntu 16.04 with a 4.4.0-38-generic kernel with a Intel HD Graphics 520 card, driven by i915_bpo

Comment: we had similar problems at the office with bad quality cables. using better shielded cables solved many problems for us. also daisychaining was a possible fallback where DisplayLink wouldn't work (during the 14.04 days).